# Messaging in ESP_BLE_MESH

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp-idf, mesh-network

I would like to ask for help with my BLE Mesh project.

My task is to create a Mesh network with the following topology:

- There are about 15 devices that read information from some sensor and once every N seconds send data (just a number from 0 to 300) to the main device. These devices should consume little power.
- There is ONE master device/gateway that needs to receive data from all other devices on the network and forward those messages to my android app. The master device also has an unlimited power supply.
- There are Relay devices that help to deliver messages from devices with sensors to the main device. These devices are in fixed locations and have an unlimited power supply.

I decided to build on the Vendor Model from the repository [https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/esp_ble_mesh/ble_mesh_vendor_model](https://stackoverflow.com), because it also distinguishes between the main device - Client and slave devices - Server, and also allows you to automate the provisioning process.

The problem is that the Servers in the Vendor Model example send messages to the Client only in response to a message from that very master inside the example_ble_mesh_custom_model_cb(esp_ble_mesh_model_cb_event_t event, esp_ble_mesh_model_cb_param_t *param) callback:

```
static void example_ble_mesh_custom_model_cb(esp_ble_mesh_model_cb_event_t event,
                                             esp_ble_mesh_model_cb_param_t *param)
{
    switch (event) {
    case ESP_BLE_MESH_MODEL_OPERATION_EVT:
        if (param->model_operation.opcode == ESP_BLE_MESH_VND_MODEL_OP_SEND) {
            uint16_t tid = *(uint16_t *)param->model_operation.msg;
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Recv 0x%06" PRIx32 ", tid 0x%04x", param->model_operation.opcode, tid);
            esp_err_t err = esp_ble_mesh_server_model_send_msg(&vnd_models[0],
                    param->model_operation.ctx, ESP_BLE_MESH_VND_MODEL_OP_STATUS,
                    sizeof(tid), (uint8_t *)&tid);
            if (err) {
                ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to send message 0x%06x", ESP_BLE_MESH_VND_MODEL_OP_STATUS);
            }
        }
        break;
    case ESP_BLE_MESH_MODEL_SEND_COMP_EVT:
        if (param->model_send_comp.err_code) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to send message 0x%06" PRIx32, param->model_send_comp.opcode);
            break;
        }
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Send 0x%06" PRIx32, param->model_send_comp.opcode);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

while **I need Servers to be able to send messages to Client whenever they want**.

To do this, I tried to move esp_ble_mesh_server_model_send_msg() into a separate function that would be called every N seconds:

```
static void send_pulse_data(void* arg) {
    // create message
    esp_err_t err = esp_ble_mesh_server_model_send_msg(&vnd_models[0],
            param->model_operation.ctx, ESP_BLE_MESH_VND_MODEL_OP_STATUS,
            sizeof(message), (uint8_t *)&message);
    if (err) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to send message 0x%06x", ESP_BLE_MESH_VND_MODEL_OP_STATUS);
    }
}
```

, but I ran into the fact that in order to send a message to the Client, parameters such as param->model_operation.ctx are needed, which I can’t get anywhere except inside the example_ble_mesh_custom_model_cb callback.

**I would like to ask for advice** on choosing the right model, on how to send messages from the Servers to the Client for my requirements, on how to receive messages on the Client side and on what functions to use for this.
**Basically any implementation tips, code snippets or comments would be very helpful to me.**

I would also be very grateful if you could answer my questions below:

1. How to make devices with sensors consume little power? Do I need to explicitly do something for this, or is it enough to disable Relay and send messages once in a limited amount of time?
2. Is it enough to change ESP_BLE_MESH_RELAY_DISABLED to ESP_BLE_MESH_RELAY_ENABLED to enable Relay?
3. Do I need to do provisioning every time I use the devices network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example to send btmesh message :

```
void send_to_dimmer(uint8_t payload)
{
printf("payload received by send_to_dimmer() 0x%02x", payload);
esp_ble_mesh_msg_ctx_t ctx = {0};
esp_err_t err = ESP_OK;

ctx.net_idx = 0x0000;
ctx.app_idx = 0x0000;
ctx.addr = 0x0003;   /* dimmer */
ctx.send_ttl = ESP_BLE_MESH_TTL_DEFAULT;
ctx.send_rel = true;

err = esp_ble_mesh_server_model_send_msg(&vnd_models[0],&ctx,
 ESP_BLE_MESH_VND_MODEL_OP_SEND, sizeof(payload), &payload);
if (err) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Send message to dimmer failed KO");
    return;
}
else {ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Message sent to dimmer OK");}
```

}

1. How to make devices with sensors consume little power? Do I need to explicitly do something for this, or is it enough to disable Relay and send messages once in a limited amount of time?
   **=> I think the biggest problem here is the ESP32 energy consumption. Disabling relay or sending limited amount of message without using esp32 sleep capability might be useless.**
2. Is it enough to change ESP_BLE_MESH_RELAY_DISABLED to ESP_BLE_MESH_RELAY_ENABLED to enable Relay?
   **=> normally yes. You can check if relay feature is activated in nRF mesh app for instance (if you used it ot provision your nodes).**
3. Do I need to do provisioning every time I use the devices network?
   **Normally no, in menuconfig, you can find ESP BLE mesh persistent storage option, so that you device will reconnect to network without problem.**

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked like a charm for me! Meanwhile I faced a similar problem which I believe will not bypass anyone who uses this topology and your solution in particular: 

When at least 4 servers send messages to the client every second, the system discards most of them, suspecting a Replay attack. Console displays messages like: «BLE_MESH: Replay: src 0x0005 dst 0x0001 seq 0x000046».
CONFIG_BLE_MESH_CRPL is 256, more than needed. Changing message frequency allows more devices, but not applicable here.

Maybe you have any ideas how to fix/avoid this behaviour?

Comment: I am very happy to have helped you. Indeed it is difficult to find help or examples with bluetooth mesh. I have been struggling these last 4 months to make my network work. 
Regarding the replay problem, CONFIG_BLE_MESH_CRPL is here to limit the number of elements a node can communicate with and this has no link with the sequence number problem you have. If a message with a sequence number n from one of the four severs arrives to the client, after another message with seq number n+1, this kind of warning happens «BLE_MESH: Replay: src 0x0005 dst 0x0001 seq 0x000046».

Comment: At quite high frequency (every second), I am not surprised this kind of problem happen. It is even worse when messages are segmented. I tried to make a bluetooth mesh sensor (with multiple data, so message is segmented) send data every second, and the client is not handling it correctly neither.

Comment: I will soon post a message (here and on esp32.com) with sequence number problem I also encounter, this arises to me whenever there is a IV update. I will let you know about it. Please continue to keep me posted about your problem in bluetooth mesh. Good luck !

Comment: Last but not least, I think bluetooth mesh is wonderful due to interoperability, the standardisation of model, speed etc... but the replay problem (which relates to security) looks difficult to manage.

Comment: Sorry for my many comments, maybe you should try to put this option ctx.send_rel = false; message will be sent faster (but with less reliability) and it might prevent the replay problem.

Comment: Hey again :) I tried "ctx.send_rel = false," but no luck. The good news is that I managed to make 6 devices work together smoothly by reducing the payload size to 8 bytes and removing segmentation. It's the only working option for now, though it means sacrificing some useful information. 

Mesh is really a very interesting technology, but unfortunately it makes you suffer too often. I hope we will come out of this fight victorious :)

Comment: Maybe have a try for the client with this menuconfig setting 'Minimum frequency that the RPL gets updated in storage'. Default value is 0. Try a higher value, like 60 seconds. I hope the client will thus not saved RPL seq number of servers immediately, and will not discard message anymore.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem? 3 months later I still haven't been able to deal with it...

Comment: I think in your case one option to consider is to disable the mesh replay control function.
In ESP-IDF 5.2, this function is *static bool rpl_check_and_store(struct bt_mesh_net_rx *rx, struct bt_mesh_rpl **match)* located in {IDF ENV}/components/bt/esp_ble_mesh/core/rpl.c
It might be another file in another version of ESP IDF.

This function includes this code
if ( (!rx->old_iv && rpl->old_iv) || rpl->seq < rx->seq ) {
   if (match) {*match = rpl;} else {bt_mesh_update_rpl(rpl, rx);}
   return false
}

You can try removing the following condition (rpl->seq < rx->seq).

Comment: You could also try to activate relay function only on a limited set of devices (rather than activating it by default to all devices), it might improve message delivery by reducing redundancies. But I think the radical method is to trick the replay control function as suggested above.